# How to inspect and change angular objects from chrome console

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking at a angular webpage and I see an object called vm. I expect to be able to inspect it with `console.log(vm)` but I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: vm is not defined(…)
```

How can I inspect this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Not directly from the console because this is code that is only relevant to its own isolated scope / closure. The only global object you will have access to is `angular`. If you wish to inspect it, you have to do it directly from the source code, by adding a `console.log($scope);` in your desired controller. By the way, vm stands for View Model, and it's probably just a generic alias for a longer controller name.

**Edit (2018):**

With the developers tool window open select the desired element (Cmd + Shift + C) and then in the console run

```
let scope = angular.element($0).scope()
```

This will let you access any public attributes that have been assigned to the element's scope.
Note, it is possible that this only works in localhost, and might not on production.

Comment: So there's no way to interact with angular from outside? That seems like a big drawback.

Comment: It's actually a positive thing (from a security standpoint), because you don't want malicious people to have access to your code and change important information. Imagine if all someone had to do to get premium access to your site was change `vm.auth.expirationDate = 2524626000000`. There goes your company's revenue. Also, in general it's good practice to not expose variables globally to avoid name collisions, etc.

Comment: Maybe, anything important probably shouldn't be exposed at all though.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate $scope properties if you set a breakpoint in the Chrome debugger so that it breaks in your controller. You can't do it if you just open the Chrome dev tools while your controller code is not executing.